# How to take the integral $\int_0^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am not sure if $a$ is a constant or is a parameter. if I take it as a constant therefore I get the following steps:

$$\int_0^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$
so usual steps like $t = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}, t^2 = a^2-x^2$ and so on, do not match with the answer.

Comment: @M.Mass here $a$ is a constant and $x$ is the one which varies from $0$ to $a$ . We can be more helpful if you show all the steps after you made the substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
x=a\cos t,\quad dx=-a\sin t\:dt,
$$ one gets
$$
\int_0^a x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=a^4\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2t\cdot\sin^2t\:dt=\frac{a^4}4\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2(2t)\:dt
$$ the latter integral is then evaluated classically.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also done by using the concept of differentiation under integral sign.  Let $$F(a)=\int_0^a x^2 \sqrt{a^2-x^2} dx$$ Then $$F'(a)=\int_0^a x^2 \frac{2a}{2 \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$ Now write $x^2$ as$-(a^2-x^2-a^2)$ So that $$F'(a)=-a \int_0^a \sqrt{a^2-x^2} dx + a^3 \int_0^a  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$ which can be evaluated using classical formulas.